# why test coverage is not 100%

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine

I wrote a method which returns true if there are folders left in the modal to be added and return false if there are no folders left in the modal to be added to the application

my method in angular/typesrcipt

```
    ifAllFoldersHaveBeenAdded() {
        let added = false;
        let folderToExclude = find(this.bdDataModel.lenderDefinedFolders, { 
 name: 'Correspondence' });
        let foldersToBeChecked = without(this.bdDataModel.lenderDefinedFolders, folderToExclude);

        for (let i = 0; i < foldersToBeChecked.length; i++) {
            let folderPresent = find(this.bdDataModel.folders, { name: foldersToBeChecked[i].name });
            if (folderPresent) {
                added = true;

            } else {
                added = false;
                return added;
            }

        }
        return added;
    }
```

my test...

```
describe('ifAllFoldersHaveBeenAdded()', () => {
            it('returns false if there are folders left in the modal to be added', () => {
                let added = false;
                $ctrl.bdDataModel.folders;
                $ctrl.foldersToBeChecked = [{ name: 'FMS' }, { name: 'Other' }];
                $ctrl.folderPresent = { name: 'FMS' };

                $ctrl.ifAllFoldersHaveBeenAdded();
                added = true;
                expect(added).toEqual(true);

            });

            it('returns true is all folders have been added to the application', () => {
                let added = false;
                $ctrl.bdDataModel.folders;
                $ctrl.foldersToBeChecked = [{ name: 'FMS' }, { name: 'Other' }];
                $ctrl.folderPresent = { name: 'LMI' };

                $ctrl.ifAllFoldersHaveBeenAdded();
                expect(added).toEqual(false);
            });

        });
```

Both tests pass but icov coverage report is marking the following lines as uncovered...

```
find(this.bdDataModel.folders, { name: foldersToBeChecked[i].name });
            if (folderPresent) {
                added = true;
            }
            else {
                added = false;
                return added;
            }
```

please tell what i should add in the test to have a 100% test coverage for this unit test.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is so much wrong with your test. First off, you need to get rid of the local `added` variables completely. Doing something like the following

```
added = true;
expect(added).toEqual(true);
```

Is essentially the same as doing `expect(true).toBe(true)`

Next, the `folderPresent` and `foldersToBeChecked` variables are local to the `ifAllFoldersHaveBeenAdded` function. They are not controller variables. You don't need to set `$ctrl.folderPresent` or `$ctrl.foldersToBeChecked` in your test.

You need to define these two variables `$ctrl.bdDataModel.lenderDefinedFolders` and `$ctrl.bdDataModel.folders`

Because `lenderDefinedFolders` is undefined the length of `foldersToBeChecked` in your function is going to be 0. So the `for` loop will never execute.

Your test should look something like this:

```
it('returns false if there are folders left in the modal to be added', () => {
   $ctrl.bdDataModel.lenderDefinedFolders = [{ //add lender defined folders here }]
   $ctrl.bdDataModel.folders = [{ //add some folders here}]

   let added = $ctrl.ifAllFoldersHaveBeenAdded();
   expect(added).toEqual(true);
});
```

Comment: i updated the test u given with the appropriate folder names for "true" and "false" cases but it returning false for "true" case which u given.

Comment: This folder `foldersToBeChecked[i].name` needs to exist in both `bdDataModel.folders` and `bdDataModel.lenderDefinedFolders`. Are you sure that is the case? I don't see any reason it would fail unless it didn't exist in both places.

Comment: describe('ifAllFoldersHaveBeenAdded()', () => {
   it('returns true is all folders have been added to the application', () => {
    $ctrl.bdDataModel.lenderDefinedFolders = [{ name: 'FMS' }];
    $ctrl.foldersToBeChecked = [{ name: 'FMS' }];
    $ctrl.bdDataModel.folders = [{ name: ' FMS' }];

    let added = $ctrl.ifAllFoldersHaveBeenAdded();
    expect(added).toEqual(true);
    
   });      my new test should return true but returning false

Comment: however i made that foldersToBeChecked , a controller array

Comment: and uncovered line is just  "added = true; " i.e the 9th line of my method and coverage report says "If path not taken"

Comment: mush appreciated your time n efforts